# jquery LOAD and bootstrap 4 issues

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to do the following.

`<button data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Details</button>`

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="bodyContent"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $('.bodyContent').load('http://www.google.com');
 })
```

However, when I click the button and the model loads up, the content is blank. I am not sure what I'm doing wrong here? I've tried it tons of different ways, but this should be correct.

Comment: You cannot load `http://www.google.com` using Ajax. That is a different domain from yours. Google does not accept cross-origin loads. Some site (specific resources on some sites, to be exact) do... But in this case, you'll get a CORS error in console.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when you call `.load()`, you want a callback function to actually put the content in there.  For example, the code below would work well for you:

```
$('body').load(url, function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
   $('.bodyContent').html(responseTxt);
});
```

Also, the minified version of JQuery doesn't have the `.load()` function in it.  Only the full version has that.  You should only load the full version, never two different versions at once!

Update: I have a JSFiddle snippet that works fine.  You should see `Use POST method for /echo/html, see http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html` when you click the button.  That's still a legit answer though :)

[LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/whn5aomx/17/)

The only JQuery you need loaded is the latest version.  Don't get the "slim" one either.  Minified ("min") is great, do that, but don't do slim.  The code below works excellently:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you show a fiddle example or snippet? I'm not sure how to implement this.

Comment: Working on it.  Try to replace the `$('.bodyContent').load('http://www.google.com');` line with what I have.

Comment: Pretty sure you made this way more difficult. I just wanna show google. Nothing else.

Comment: As Louys said, "And using the full version, you'll encounter a CORS issue tring to load www.google.com:

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."  == this means that you cannot do it anyway.  This isn't more complicated.  Just remove the extract JQuery loading lines, and add the small bit of code I listed.  (I made a bit of an update so it's [less intimidating](https://jsfiddle.net/whn5aomx/19/))

Comment: The point is that **you cannot** show Google that way... That is part of my answer about CORS issue.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Exactly.  I don't know why google needs to be loaded (unless it's a stand-in for a different link - which should've been said anyway).  If you want search functionality, check [this out](https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/4513903?hl=en).

Comment: @Ka_ren Can you edit your fiddle to show it opening google in a modal? Right now it's just showing POST text, which does not help in showing me how to add an external link into a bootstrap modal. I know how to add text.

Comment: @KevinM1990112qwq Literally all you need to change is one parameter.  Here, in [this revision](https://jsfiddle.net/whn5aomx/20/) I put it into the `url` variable for you.  You can make it `https://google.com`, but that won't work for security reasons (as we've said).

Comment: If your saying your answer will NOT work for my question, then how do I make it work?..... Because right now, this makes no sense. Giving me a random answer but saying it's so easy, but it wont work because of security. It wont work because of googles security? I'm not following you here. what if the URL was just a placeholder for home.php How could I make it display home.php then? This is getting hella confusing, lol.

Comment: I rolled back to my original question and told you, the added issues with versions was because what someone else added.

Comment: If google is a placeholder, change the URL variable in my JSFiddle link from my previous comment to **whatever** URL you intend to use instead.  That will work, as long as it's on your site. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/whn5aomx/21/)

Comment: If you try to load a ressource from the same domain as yours... Like `home.php`... Your code should work as is. Do you have errors in [console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)?

Comment: Also, your answer your doing on click event and not my original modal show event? Is that for a specific reason? Is there an issue with bootstrap, or did you just want to change it? Because again, the question was around bootstrap 4 modals and jquery.

Comment: Sorry @KevinM1990112qwq .  I couldn't get the modal event to trigger.  I think using the on click works better.  That was for my testing - sorry!

Comment: So how does your code work with modals then? Because as of right now, if I change it back to modals and add the URL param, when I hit the button, it loads the modal for a split second before refreshing the current page.

Comment: Again, sorry.  I couldn't get the modal event to trigger.  I'm working on a fix rn.

Comment: @Ka_ren but I need a model to show, not just a new div.

Comment: Maybe it is a current issue with bootstrap modals, because this has been my entire issue.

Comment: @KevinM1990112qwq I have it working now.  I don't think it's bootstrap.  When I removed some links, I removed one of the important bootstrap ones.  Fixed that.  Take this code, and change the `url` variable as needed: https://jsfiddle.net/whn5aomx/33/

Comment: Lol, still not showing anything when you change the URL param.

Comment: Which part?  Have you actually done what I said you should do?  Or are you still staring at JSFiddle?  You should paste the code into your website (backup the page first) and test it, with the URL variable set to what you want.